# c code for MQTT Connect API

Tags: activemq-classic, connect, mqtt

I have to write a simple c code for CONNECT API function in MQTT to an Active MQ broker without using the existing libraries. I am new to this protocol and any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you'll just want to get the MQTT specification. The current version, 3.1, can be found here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-mqtt/index.html

The protocol is currently undergoing standardisation at Oasis. You can find the draft version of the updated spec through the documents link at https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=mqtt , but you should bear in mind that Active MQ almost certainly only supports version 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that explains how to write a simple MQTT client https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/write_your_own_mqtt_client_without_using_any_api_in_minutes1?lang=en . You will need to code the required part of the MQTT client.